# Stop prompts to open the word document every time you click on the link if the document is already open in the desktop word

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word

If we open a document using
`"ms-word:ofe|u|https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site}/Shared%20Documents/TESTnlbt/v.2%20-%20NDA%20for%20TACO%20BELL.docx"` link  on a browser we get a pop-up to open word document and the document gets opened up on my desktop and it is always open, but when we again hit the same link the pop-up again reappears, which we don't want , how do we stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default open settings for files in the SharePoint Online is an available solution to stop pop-up window.

1.Site settings -> Site collection features -> Deactivate Open Documents in Client Applications by Default feature.

2.Library settings -> Advanced settings -> Select Open in the browser.